# Unable to Bundle Install in new Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a Rails app, but it fails bundle install the required gems. The error I get is this:

> The deployment setting requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have
>
> checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.

I've tried running this with the --no-deployment flag but that doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: So there is no `gemfile.lock` file and it is saying you need that.  Is `gemfile.lock` included in the `gitignore` or something?

Comment: Do you use Capistrano?

Comment: I do not use Capistrano and there is no gemfile.lock.

Comment: Does Gemfile.lock exist in the same dir as Gemfile? Have you checked the file permission (644)?

Comment: @DannyS. You probably not just trying to install dependencies. bundle install has nothing to do with "deploying" code.  What exactly is the command you run when you get this error? Can you post entire output and not just this error? This isn't enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but worth checking. After creating the Rails app (`rails new my-app`) did you `cd` into your app's root directory (`cd my-app`) before running `bundle install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by trying to copy a gemfile.lock file from another project. I got this error when i tried running bundle install.

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the
C:/Users/Danny/Desktop/paper-db/Gemfile freeze
by running `bundle config --delete frozen`.
```

I ran the `bundle config --delete frozen` command and now i can run bundle install and generate a gemfile.lock file for my project. It seems like the default mode for my project was deployment mode for some reason, even though i tried reinstalling rails and bundler several times... Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same problem as me!